# Is using LAMP as a server component for my game viable?

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I've been working on a pseudo-multiplayer game that stores each player's important data on my MySQL database. The game is similar to Clash of Clans in that players build their own bases and may choose to attack other players' bases.

To prevent cheating, all important functions are run on my server via PHP. For instance, if a player wants to build a house, the server is told: Player wants to build BUILDING_A to grid{x,y}, and the PHP script checks from the database if the area is free, if the player has the tech, the money, etc. to do so.

All these functions are relatively simple. They just check who tried to access the database and if they can do what they wanted to do. Then the server will update the player's data in the database and return a message to the device.

---

So, essentially my game will always follow the same process:

1) Player device makes a request,

2) Server authenticates the player and permits or denies the request,

3) Server sends player device a response and the device follows it.

---

But I am not sure as to how viable or scaleable my approach is. I've just been testing it alone and it works well, but let's say that I get 100 or 1000 players in the first week. There may be a few hundred server requests per second at peak, where PHP scripts are called and the database is accessed and updated. What if it becomes a hit and there are thousands of people accessing my PHP scripts and database simultaneously?

Is this sort of approach viable at all to begin with? If my server(s) were powerful enough, can a single PHP script be accessed by so many people at the same time, and can the server write to my database hundreds of times within a second? Would it queue the operations, would it ignore some, would overlapping operations just fail?

For instance, if I paid for AWS EC2 and setup my LAMP there, could this kind of system work or would I run into some sort of limitation or issues that I am not aware of?

Comment: As I understand your application, I think you should consider a message-broker and web-sockets instead of a pull-based solution. If you're coming from PHP, have a look at RabbitMQ. It would reduce traffic and scale better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PHP script be accessed by so many people at the same time, and can the server write to my database hundreds of times within a second? Would it queue the operations, would it ignore some, would overlapping operations just fail?

- Hundreds per second -- OK.  Thousands --It depends.
- Queue the operations -- Yes, but this is rather rapid; the operations will mostly be performed in parallel.
- Ignore some -- No.  Well, if they remain queue up for so long that it exceeds `lock_wait_timeout`, which defaults as 50 seconds.  (Not likely to happen.)
- 'just fail' -- No.

You should probably plan to have enough RAM to handle all the data involved.  (It sounds like this will be no problem.)  If queries have to reach into the disk too often, *that* becomes a limitation on scaling the game.  AWS EC2 uses SSDs, correct?  (HDDs would be too slow.)

Are graphics involved?  What handles that?  Is it entirely in each user's client browser?  I ask because if there are SQL queries involved in redrawing the screen, *that* could be a heavy load.

It sounds like the typical 'session' is

- Start up PHP
- Connect to MySQL
- `SELECT` user info
- do some PHP processing
- `UPDATE user info

and that will happen, on average once every few seconds.  A thousand users doing that should be easy to achieve.

That assumes it is a single-person game.  If, instead, it is a multi-user game, won't the "newly built house" need to be broadcast to all other users?

Comment: Graphics would not be involved. I have a MySQL table where every player is represented by a row that has things like their ID, amount of gold, a json string of their base layout, etc. All graphics and such would be handled in Android/iOS app. The app would send the server the player's command, like "player wants to build house to location x,y". The server then loads the player's data and checks if the player has enough money and if the building area is free. If all works, then server will update the player's database entry. Then the server returns message like "success" or "fail", and why.

Comment: @JamesT. - I added to my Answer.

Comment: Well, it is a pseudo-multiplayer game. The information needs to only be updated for the player whose city it is when the action is taken. The idea is similar to Clash of Clans in that every player sees their own city and when a new house starts to build, no other player is notified. Other players may view each others cities via different commands, but in these cases only the other player's city's layout would be returned to their device from the server and the player's app would render the city based on the given information. So, when something is built, only the player who built it knows it.

Comment: @JamesT. - Well, all the other traffic will be part of how well the system scales.  So think through a 'typical' minute of play, listing all the typical SQL queries.  List them like I tried to do.  _Then_ we can discuss scaling.

Comment: @JamesT. - And I assume from your last Comment that if 3 other players are in _my_ city, then when _I_ build a house, some `SELECT` is needed to discover them, plus somehow a message need to go to each of them.  Meanwhile, my new house has no impact on the rest of the thousand users.

Comment: @JamesT. - So, ...  If the discovery of "who else is in my city" needs to be efficiently coded, else it could be the bottleneck of performance.

Comment: Basically, whenever some other player loads your city, they just load the layout/map of the city once. If you decide to build a new house, it will not be updated for anyone unless they (leave) and reload your city. The only time that a player can really view your city is if they plan to attack it. And, like in Clash of Clans, you can't attack players who are online, so it isn't even possible for someone to view your city while you are building it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, more than 10k request per second can be easily managed by LAMP environment.

Only one suggestion here instead of `Apache2` server use `Nginx` server that perform better than `Apache2` server. As `Nginx` is still the better choice for performance in most situations.

Refer: https://theorganicagency.com/blog/apache-vs-nginx-performance-comparison/

In case want to do benchmarking by yourself than you can use : https://www.litespeedtech.com/benchmarks/php-hello-world

As you are planning to deploy it on EC2 for initially you can use m5a.large and later on popularity create(clone) one more m5a.large Ubuntu server and put both of them under ELB.

Best of luck!

Comment: "in most situations" - given a well defined demand capacity, Apache + mod_php, particularly for a data-service application will outperform nginx+php-fpm by quite a large margin. The difference is les clear with mixed content / loads regulalry exceeding planned capacity / cheap minimal hosting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably will want to look for an "AJAX server" or "Remote Procedure Call (RPC) server" package written in the language of your choice.  You don't actually need "a web server" to do this particular job.  You can find more-specialized and lighter-weight tools that are specifically targeted for *this* purpose.  (And for "containerized deployments," which are commonly used for tasks like this.)

Vendors such as Rackspace write very extensively on their web site about various ways to deploy "dynamically scalable servers."  I believe that they still have a write-up by a company which sells a mobile application used by "soccer moms."  When nobody's using the app, the corresponding "containers" aren't running.  When the weekend comes and every mommy is thumbing their screen while watching their little darlings run around the field, an adjustable number of containers dynamically come online to handle the load ... then eventually die off again.

So, yes, your reasoning is sound and your requirement is a very common one.  You can stand on the shoulders of giants here.

Answer (score 0):

> let's say that I get 100 or 1000 players in the first week

I think you don`t have to worry about configuration for this number of player. But I am going write what possible things that you should be aware of in order to make your system robust enough to handle large traffic

check for `mysql max_connections limit`

check for `apache2 MaxRequestWorkers limit` for more info [view this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/796968/apache-2-4-max-concurrent-users-limit)

check for `max number of open files at system level` for more info [view this](https://medium.com/@muhammadtriwibowo/set-permanently-ulimit-n-open-files-in-ubuntu-4d61064429a)

If your number of player increases you can use `ELB` with multiple instances and `MySql Master Slave`

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer to this, but for a well written application running on a well configured server, the execution of logic will only take a fraction of the time taken to process a request - response times are normally dominated by the network round trip time and the time spent talking to the DBMS. Where multi-user systems often fail to scale is in handling concurrency; things the programmer think will run in parallel need to run sequentially and may use locking to enforce this. Hence the choice of programming language (as long as it is not CGI, where a program is stated up to handle each request) doesn't really matter all that much.

You need to be able to benchmark each of these operations - collecting data on the end-to-end response times on the client and collecting that back at a central location (not necessarily in real time) and gathering metrics about database wait time in your application.

PHP sessions can be a major bottleneck - also try to minimize the number of calls each request makes to the database.

I've seen bloated Wordpress installs struggling to turn around a request in under 3 seconds with 256Mb of RAM and not supporting more than 20 concurrent connections on a reasononably specced host - and I've also seen content management systems capable of handling a request in 10milliseconds with a 4Mb RAM limit. Roughly a difference in capacity of over a thousand fold.